# Cucumber reports not generating

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, report

I'm having an issue with cucumber reports not generating. I'm running the tests with IntelliJ.

Here's my pom:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I've created a RunCucumberTest.java class, with the following:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/reports", "json:target/reports/cucumber.json"},
                 glue = {"com.PACKAGE.featureTests"})
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

I've run it successfully with the IntelliJ plugin, with failures and without (I know some issues have been that the report doesn't generate when there are failures). But in neither case will any report be created in my target folder.

Thoughts?

Comment: The cucumbe report is generated based on the json result file. Where do you place that file in your setup?

Comment: I updated my RunCucumberFeatureTests class in the question to have "json:target/reports/cucumber.json", but no json file is generated. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Yes. Are you running this from Command line? the scope of cucumber - junit is shown as test. should not this be compile ?

Comment: Is there something about the file ending in `Tests.java` instead of `Test.java` ?

Comment: No, like I mentioned, I'm running the test via IntelliJ. I've also tried changing the filename to RunCucumberTest.java (and edited above) but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by upgrading to 5.1.3 and they generate fine there.

Answer (score 0):

"ERROR: Build step failed with exception when using Cucumber Reports" occurs in all the latest jenkins versions to solve this

While adding post-build action to add cucumber reports option in jenkins no need to provide the JSON Reports Path/Location instead just add the File Include Pattern as **/cucumber.json.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byTXi.jpg)

This will fix the issue and Cucumber Reports will be generated.

Comment: My question is for intelliJ, not Jenkins.